# is there a Linux command like top to view CPU utilization in the Past?

Tags: rhel, performance, top, cpu-usage

If I use the `top -i` in Red Hat 7.4, I can view CPU utilization and the PID of the respective process in real time. Is there a way to view a capture of CPU utilization and PID for a date/time in the past?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  But system-wide cpu stats can often be viewed using `sar -u` or `sar -u -f /var/log/sa/saNN` where NN is the day of the month.  For more info on that look at `man sar`.

If you really wanted `top -i` collected you could create a `cron` job to keep recording the output though.